# Overlapping polygons in Python PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, polygon, computational-geometry

Instead of overwriting the overlapping regions of multiple polygons by the value of the last polygon drawn, I would like to draw the mean value of these polygons.
Is this possible in Python PIL?

The overlapping pixels in the example should have the value of 1.5.

In the full working program I have to draw about 100000 polygons (that may or may not intersect) on a very large grid which is the reason I use PIL instead of Numpy.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.new('F', (50, 50), 0)

ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([(20, 20), (20, 40), (40, 30), (30, 20)],
                            fill=1., outline=None)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon([(10, 5), (10, 25), (25, 25), (25, 10)],
                            fill=2., outline=None)

myimg = np.ma.masked_equal(np.array(img), 0.)
plt.imshow(myimg, interpolation="None")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [clipping one polygon to the other polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection) to produce their intersection, and then drawing that intersection polygon? Or are there so many overlapping polygons in your full data set that `O(2^n)` of the polygons' power set grows unacceptably?

Comment: If you can render polygons onto a numpy array (don't know how, [maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587839/drawing-polygons-in-numpy-arrays) is a start?), then you can maintain an array of polygon counts at each pixel and an array of accumulated values. Then the mean value will be accumulated_values / counts, where counts > 0

Comment: I added the approximate (large) number of possibly intersecting polygons to my question. This is why I would like to avoid Numpy, because the performance of PIL in this respect is much higher.

Comment: Could you use a transparency layer in the image? Then the overlaying polygons would naturally "blend" over each other? I'm not sure though, if PIL supports multi-channel images with float32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest `scikit-image`, `skimage.draw.polygon()` returns coordinates in the polygon. Here is an example. Create some random polygon data first:

```
import pylab as pl
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from skimage import draw

W, H = 800, 600

def make_poly(x0, y0, r, n):
    a = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, n, endpoint=False)
    x = x0 + r * np.cos(a)
    y = y0 + r * np.sin(a)
    return y, x

count_buf = np.zeros((H, W))
sum_buf = np.zeros((H, W))

N = 2000

polys = []
for i in range(N):
    x0, y0, r, n = randint(10, W-10), randint(10, H-10), randint(10, 50), randint(3, 10)
    polys.append((make_poly(x0, y0, r, n), randint(1, 10)))
```

Then draw the polygons:

```
for (y, x), v in polys:
    rr, cc = draw.polygon(y, x, (H, W))
    count_buf[rr, cc] += 1
    sum_buf[rr, cc] += v

mean_buf = np.zeros_like(sum_buf)
mask = count_buf > 0
mean_buf[mask] = sum_buf[mask] / count_buf[mask]
```

the time is about 1.5s on my pc to draw 2000 polygons with average radius 30 px.

Here is the result:

[image]

If you need better speed, you can copy the following code in scikit-image:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/draw/_draw.pyx#L189

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/_shared/geometry.pyx#L7

and change the `count_buf` and `sum_buf` in the for loop if `point_in_polygon()` returns True.

**Edit**

Here is the Cython code:

```
%%cython
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport ceil

cdef unsigned char point_in_polygon(double[::1] xp, double[::1] yp,
                                           double x, double y):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef unsigned char c = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t j = xp.shape[0] - 1
    for i in range(xp.shape[0]):
        if (
            (((yp[i] <= y) and (y < yp[j])) or
            ((yp[j] <= y) and (y < yp[i])))
            and (x < (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i])
        ):
            c = not c
        j = i
    return c


cdef class PolygonAccumulator:

    cdef int width, height
    cdef int[:, ::1] count_buf
    cdef double[:, ::1] sum_buf

    def __cinit__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        shape = (height, width)
        self.count_buf = np.zeros(shape, dtype=int)
        self.sum_buf = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)

    def reset(self):
        self.count_buf[:, :] = 0
        self.sum_buf[:, :] = 0

    def add_polygon(self, ya, xa, double value):
        cdef Py_ssize_t minr = int(max(0, np.min(ya)))
        cdef Py_ssize_t maxr = int(ceil(np.max(ya)))
        cdef Py_ssize_t minc = int(max(0, np.min(xa)))
        cdef Py_ssize_t maxc = int(ceil(np.max(xa)))

        cdef double[::1] x = xa
        cdef double[::1] y = ya

        cdef Py_ssize_t r, c

        maxr = min(self.height - 1, maxr)
        maxc = min(self.width  - 1, maxc)

        for r in range(minr, maxr+1):
            for c in range(minc, maxc+1):
                if point_in_polygon(x, y, c, r):
                    self.count_buf[r, c] += 1
                    self.sum_buf[r, c] += value

    def mean(self):
        count_buf = self.count_buf.base
        sum_buf = self.sum_buf.base
        mean_buf = np.zeros_like(sum_buf)
        mask = count_buf > 0
        mean_buf[mask] = sum_buf[mask] / count_buf[mask]
        return mean_buf
```

To draw the polygons:

```
pa = PolygonAccumulator(800, 600)
for (y, x), value in polys:
    pa.add_polygon(y, x, value)
pl.imshow(pa.mean(), cmap="gray")
```

It's about 4.5x faster than `skimage.draw.polygon()`

Comment: Thank you for this idea! Unfortunately it takes twice the time on my machine compared to the PIL method, but calculates the overlaps correctly. Could you explain how to improve the speed in more detail, please? Thank you!

Comment: @HyperCube, I added Cython code that maybe 2x faster than PIL.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but how do I call/embed the Cython code?

Comment: If you don't know how to compile cython code, please read the document: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html.
If you use IPython notebook, run `%load_ext cythonmagic`, and then the cython code, and then `import sys; sys.modules[PolygonAccumulator.__module__].__file__` to get the compiled module. copy the module file to your script folder, and rename it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a compile error: hyrycode.pyx:9:43: Expected an identifier or literal. "hyrycode" is a pyx-file of your Cython code.

Comment: What's the cython version?

Comment: 0.15.1 on a debian server. I'll try to compile it on a different machine.

Comment: 0.15.1 is very old, try versions after 0.20

Comment: I don't understand why it is complaining... which variable has the dtype "long"?
    pa = PolygonAccumulator(800, 600)
  File "PolygonAccumulator.pyx", line 35, in PolygonAccumulator.PolygonAccumulator.__cinit__ (/home/jay/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyrex/PolygonAccumulator.c:2057)
    self.count_buf = np.zeros(shape, dtype=int)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'